# How to use JS Arrays as keys when declaring JS-dicts in QML

Tags: javascript, qt, dictionary, qml, qtquick2

In the QML JS implementation, I can write this:

```
property var dict1: ({})
property var dict2: { 'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3 }
// property var dict3: { [0,0]:1, [1,4]:5, [2,4]:3 } // can't do this!

// but can do this.
Component.onCompleted: {
    dict1[[0,0]] = 1
    dict1[[1,4]] = 5
    dict1[[2,4]] = 3
}
```

So the last part uses JS-Arrays as keys in the dict. However a declaration as in Line 3 (dict3) is not possible. I don't get, why the one notation should not be possible, if the expected result is possible by other means.

So my question is: How would it be possible to instantiate the `dict` without the need of the `Component.onCompleted` or similar hack?
If there is no way to do it, a reason why, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS Objects keys are always strings. There is no such thing as an array-as-key or object-as-key.

> `dict1[[0,0]] = 1` is **strictly equivalent** to `dict1['0,0'] = 1`.

Bottom-line is property assignment and property access automatically cast the key to string.

---

Try the following:

```
dict1[dict2] = 42
console.log(JSON.stringify(dict1))
```

> **Output:** {"0,0":1,"1,4":5,"2,4":3,"[object Object]":42}

The expression `dict2`was cast to its string representation and used as key. You can then access the value 42 by using any of the following

- `dict1["[object Object]"]`
- `dict1[dict2]`
- `dict1[dict1]` since `toString(dict1)` returns `"[object Object]"`
- `dict1[({})]` since `toString(({}))` returns `"[object Object]"`

These casts are not performed the same way at object creation, meaning you can't do `property var dict2: { [1,2]:3 }`. However, `property var dict2: { "1,2":3 }` will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks! Now it makes sense to me!